# Converting social-network-quality text into normal text

Tags: nlp

I'm looking for a program that can convert social-network-quality text into normal texts.

Examples:

- "c u at da club 2nite" -> "see you at the club tonight".
- "k gr8!" ->"ok great!"
- "I'll c you there" -> "I will see you there"

Any desktop OS, any license, any price is fine. My preference goes to Windows 7, gratis, open source, Python, if there is the choice, but my main focus is on the quality of the output. I am mostly interested in texts written in English.

I am aware of [TextCleanser](https://github.com/gouwsmeister/TextCleanser) (1) it's a good start, but I am looking for a tool that yields better results.

(1) suggests a list of transformation types:

[image]

---

(1) Gouws, Stephan, et al. "[Contextual bearing on linguistic variation in social media.](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?cluster=8756462528805987216&hl=en&as_sdt=0,22)" Proceedings of the Workshop on Languages in Social Media. Association for Computational Linguistics, 2011.